# Measure bars only in line above the text (songs Package)

Tags: songs

When using the songs package, I like to use the measure bars to indicate when some chords are only, for example, two strums each.

The usual approach seems to be to just put the | pipe symbol in the line directly; this results in a bar in both the text line and the chords line. I'd prefer the look when using it like backslash[|], which results in a bar only in the chords line. However, the text below still 'reserves' the space for the bar, which looks weird.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\noversenumbers
\begin{document}
\songsection{Worship Songs}
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                 sr={Revelation 5:13},
                 cr={Public domain.}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, | \[D]from \[Em]Whom | \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[|] \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[|] \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any workaround to do this - bar only in the chords line, without interfering with the text? This would mean that the bar is placed slightly to the left to not interfere with the next chord, I think... I had a look at the songs implementation, but as a beginner, I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can use `all\[| D]{ }creatures` to make the bar appear above the space between "all" and "creatures". Make sure not to add any additional spaces before or after `\[| D]{ }`.

[image: songs]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\noversenumbers
\begin{document}
\songsection{Worship Songs}
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
sr={Revelation 5:13},
cr={Public domain.}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, | \[D]from \[Em]Whom | \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all\[| D]{ }crea\[Em]tures\[| C]{ }here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for a slightly different result also  `\[|]\[D]crea\[Em]tures` produces the desired effect.

Comment: @domenicocamasta Yes, just note that it needs a whitespace at the beginning: `all \[|]\[D]crea\[Em]tures`. This puts the bar close to the `c` instead of the `l`, I guess it is just a matter of preference.